# Debugging CUFFTW interface plan creation

Tags: cuda, fftw, cufft

I am begining to port an existing fftw3 application to make use of the cuda fftw libraries. The initial stage is to simply replace the `fftw3.h` header with the `cufft.h` header and link the cufft libraries instead of the fftw3 libraries.

That is simple enough, and the code compiles with `nvcc`. However when I execute the code the application is unable to create a plan using the `fftw_plan_guru_dft` command (it just returns 0 instead of a valid plan).

Since there are no errors reported I am at a loss as to how I might debug this issue. `cuda-gdb` and `gdb` do not provide any further insight. They simply report

```
Error: Internal error reported by CUDA debugger API (error=7). The application cannot be further debugged.
```

**UPDATE:** So here is the minimum working example. As mentioned in my comment to Talonmies, this code is autogenerated by a scientific differential equation solver. So please excuse the function names etc.

```
#define real Re
#define imag Im

#include <complex>

#undef real
#undef imag

#include <cufftw.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
     int _transform_sizes_index = 1, _loop_sizes_index = 0;
     fftw_iodim _transform_sizes[1], _loop_sizes[2];
     _transform_sizes[0].n = 128;
     _transform_sizes[0].is = 0;
     _transform_sizes[0].os = 0;

    fftw_complex _data_in[128] = {0.};

    static fftw_plan _fftw_forward_plan = NULL;
    _fftw_forward_plan = fftw_plan_guru_dft(
          _transform_sizes_index, _transform_sizes,
          _loop_sizes_index, _loop_sizes,
          reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(_data_in),
          reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(_data_in),
          FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_PATIENT);
    if (!_fftw_forward_plan)
       printf("Error: Unable to create forward plan\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Unless anyone else knows what I am doing wrong, it looks like this particular functionality of fftw3 may not be supported by cufftw.

Comment: Can you make a repro case for this? Otherwise it is very hard to know what sort of answer you are expecting here (or what you are really asking)

Comment: Alright I'll see what I can do. The original code is auto generated from a scientific differential equation solver (xmds.org) so it is kind of a mess. I'm just looking for ideas on where to start given that the fftw_plan_guru_dft doesn't output any errors.

Comment: FYI: you can see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#fftw-supported-interface) that `fftw_plan_guru_dft()` is only partially supported in cuFFT. Are you sure your use case is supported?

Comment: Haha. It seems to both supported and unsupported. That might have something to do with it. I'll have to check it out when I am back in the office. Thanks, I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) pointed out, the `fftw_plan_guru_dft` only has partial support in the cufftw library. The above example will run if you instead make use of the basic level `fftw_plan_dft`. More concretely

```
#define real Re
#define imag Im

#include <complex>

#undef real
#undef imag

#include <cufftw.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int _transform_sizes_index = 1, _loop_sizes_index = 0;
    int _transform_sizes[1] = {128};

    fftw_complex _data_in[128] = {0.};

    static fftw_plan _fftw_forward_plan = NULL;
    _fftw_forward_plan = fftw_plan_dft(
          _transform_sizes_index, _transform_sizes,
          reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(_data_in),
          reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(_data_in),
          FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_PATIENT);
    if (!_fftw_forward_plan)
       printf("Error: Unable to create forward plan\n");

    return 0;
}
```